# One Page Anchor Scroll. Keep anchor target div below my floating menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying desperately to keep the target divs below my floating menu bar. What is the correct way of doing it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash;
        var t = $(this.hash).offset().top;
        $('.wrapper').animate({
        scrollTop: t,
        }, 800, function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

I tried adding paddings and margin through jquery .addClass without notable success. Tried repositioning the divs too. Nothing works properly.

Here the live test site im doing for a friend http://rolfvohs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the top position by adding a negative value to it.  So it your scroll is off by 200px just adjust your function;

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var target = this.hash;
            var t = $(this.hash).offset().top-200;
            $('.wrapper').animate({
            scrollTop: t,
            }, 800, function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
            });
        });
    });
```

Without the rest of your code that is my best guess.  I would actually consider a slightly different function to your scroll though.  your scrolling function seems like it jumps a bit in chrome.  Didn't test it in anything else, but maybe something like;

```
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
            || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name='+this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length){
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top-200}, 800);
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hello dimmlight. It works great. May I just ask why the scrolling works but when I click on "about" and then on "testimonials" it wont work as expected as if the offset was wrong.

Comment: It seems the scrolls dont work when im somewhere in the middle of the page

Comment: Not sure why that would be happening.  I would actually update function to select `('.animate-fast li a')`  That way it only works on that item.  Then update the  name of the div to = the href#.  So if the link is `<a href="#music>`  Then the div should have `<div name="music">`

Comment: I try this out now and let you know.

Comment: The result was the same unfortunately. I have an idea and tell me if im wrong. I could create scenarios. If user clicked on "about" then change offset when clicked on "testimonials" and succesively. So if $('Link-1]').click(function(){ then $('Link-2]') (function(){ $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top-XXX}, 800);

Comment: You would be better using a data attribute to store the offset for each element like data-offset="200" then use a variable like var divOffset = $(this).attr('data-offset'); then drop that in to the offset value.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a div to sit below a floating div, you can use CSS:

Create a div with `class="clearfix"` in your HTML

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Then in your CSS define these attributes:

```
div.clearfix {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
}
```

Try placing the new div immediately below your floated div. Anything below the new div will sit below it.